# Xtext ecore file size limited to 50kb?

Tags: java, eclipse, xtext, emf, ecore

The Xtext projects ecore file exceeds the 50kb.
The workflow generation always works fine. But when i start the editor it crashes.

If i comment out some grammar rules, reducing the ecore file size to less than 50kb it works well. But as soon it exceeds the limit following exception arise:

```
!MESSAGE com.sample.mydsl.ui.internal.MyDslActivator  - Failed to create injector for com.sample.mydsl.MyDsl
...
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Missing serialized package: myDsl.ecore
at com.sample.mydsl.myDsl.impl.MyDslPackageImpl.loadPackage(MyDslPackageImpl.java:5897)
at com.sample.mydsl.myDsl.impl.MyDslPackageImpl.init(MyDslPackageImpl.java:1084)
at com.sample.mydsl.myDsl.MyDslPackage.<clinit>(MyDslPackage.java:58)
```

I am pretty sure that it's not the rules logic itself, because i also tested to limit the  grammar to running conditions. And extended it then by mock rules to increase the file size. Anyway it crashed...

I guess the problem is lying deeper than exceptions message shows.

---

My **workflow** is configured as follows:

```
fragment = parser.antlr.XtextAntlrGeneratorFragment auto-inject {
          options = {
              classSplitting=true
              fieldsPerClass = "500" 
              methodsPerClass  = "500"
          }   
        }

same settings for XtextAntlrUiGeneratorFragment
```

Did anyone collect experience with those problem already? I would be very grateful for some suggestions.